# To move elements in Fragment when user scroll the page

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-animation

I have ViewPager with 3 Fragments. **I just want to know is it possible to move elements (ImageView, TextView, e.t.c) in Fragment when user start to scroll the page and go to another page?** What the best way to do that? Here below my code that I used before. I used it in my MainActivity. Only after test I understand that I am on the wrong way cause these code will work every time when user scroll. So is it possible to set it in Fragment?

My code that i used before in MainActivity:

```
@Override
public void transformPage(View page, float position) {
        // transformation here
        int pageWidth = page.getWidth();
        ImageView mImageViewCloud = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.cloud);
        ImageView mImageButterfly = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.butterfly);

        if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
            // This page is way off-screen to the left.
            page.setAlpha(0);

        } else if (position <= 1) { // [-1,1]

            if(mImageViewCloud!=null)mImageViewCloud.setTranslationX((float) (-(1 - position) * 0.5 * pageWidth));
            if(mImageButterfly!=null)mImageButterfly.setTranslationX((float) ((1 - position) * 1.5 * pageWidth));
            // The 0.5, 1.5, 1.7 values you see here are what makes the view move in a different speed.
            // The bigger the number, the faster the view will translate.
            // The result float is preceded by a minus because the views travel in the opposite direction of the movement.


        } else { // (1,+Infinity]
            // This page is way off-screen to the right.
            page.setAlpha(0);
        }
}
```

**Any help is appreciated. Thanks!**

**EDIT:**
**AdapterFragment.java**

```
public abstract class AdapterFragment extends Fragment {

    SparseArray<AdapterFragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<AdapterFragment>();

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        AdapterFragment fragment = (AdapterFragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        registeredFragments.remove(position);
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    }

    public void pass(int farFarAway) {
        for(int i = 0, nSize = registeredFragments.size(); i < nSize; i++)
            registeredFragments.valueAt(i).pass(farFarAway);
    }

    final int pageWidth = ViewPager.getMeasuredWidth(); //after ViewPager drawn, probably its also screen width
    final int scrollRange = (AdapterFragment.getCount()-1)*pageWidth;

    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener OPCL = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            float farFarAway=(float)(position*pageWidth+positionOffsetPixels), scrollToFactor = farFarAway/scrollRange;
            AdapterFragment.pass(farFarAway);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried [ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html)? there is a method in this interface `onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)`, last two variables might be useful for your purposes - pass move offset to all `Fragment`s, inside of them move `View`s

edit:

```
final int pageWidth=mainViewPager.getMeasuredWidth(); //after ViewPager drawn, probably its also screen width
final int scrollRange = (viewPagerCustomAdapter.getCount()-1)*pageWidth;

OnPageChangeListener onpcl = new OnPageChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                    float farFarAway=(float)(position*pageWidth+positionOffsetPixels),
                    scrollToFactor = farFarAway/scrollRange;

                    viewPagerCustomAdapter.pass(farFarAway);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                }
            };
```

`viewPagerCustomAdapter` is an adapter dispatching `farFarAway` - how much distance `ViewPager` is moved starting left edge of 0 position Fragment. how to dispatch moved value to currently existing `Fragment`s? - [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785221/retrieve-a-fragment-from-a-viewpager) and create `for` loop over all registered fragments inside adapter's `pass(int farFarAway)`. inside each Fragment you may calculate proper value for `setTranslationX`. you may also pass and use `scrollToFactor` (0.0-1.0) and position, these might be useful. e.g. position might determine if you are on current or next `Fragment`. note that default `ViewPager` memory is set to one, so there can't be more than 3 registered `Fragment`s at once (current+both next)

edit 2:

create new class and extend all your `Fragment`s used in your adapter

```
public abstract class AdapterFragment extends Fragment{
    public abstract pass(int farFarAway);
}
```

add these lines to your adapter:

```
SparseArray<AdapterFragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<AdapterFragment>();

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    AdapterFragment fragment = (AdapterFragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    registeredFragments.remove(position);
    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
}

public void pass(int farFarAway) {
    for(int i = 0, nsize = registeredFragments.size(); i < nsize; i++)
        registeredFragments.valueAt(i).pass(farFarAway);
}
```

set above `OnPageChangeListener` for your `ViewPager`. In this way every Fragment gets current scroll position. so an example of use in one of your `Fragment`s

```
public void pass(int farFarAway){
    imageView.setTranslationX(farFarAway/10); //sample value 10, farFarAway is too big value for moving any View
}
```

your `ImageView` should move when while swiping `ViewPager`, adjust as you want. This whole post is almost full solution, should be useful...

PS. code not tested, might be some syntax or other bugs

Comment: Hello @snachmsm ! I found that method too before but i dont understand how exactly this method works in my case. How to set positionOffset? Can you show me example. As I said I have 3 pages: 1page(position 0), 2 page(position 1), 3 page(position 2). As example user want to scroll from 1 page to 2 page.

Comment: check out edit with some sample code and suggestions

Comment: Hello @snachmsm again, I am not sure that I understand your idea. As a matter of fact I have my own ViewPagerAdapter to change Fragments. I will update my post with it. You can check it. Anyway can you show me concrete solution to my task please cause i cant catch your idea!

Comment: Hello @snachmsm I created new AdapterFragment.class as you said. I edited my post with code of that class. Can you check it? Is it ok? Cause i have some mistakes as: Cannot resolve method instantiateItem, destroyItem, getCount, pass. Another mistake in code is: Non-static method 'getMeasuredWidht()' cannot be refenced from static from a static context... Can you check it? Maybe I'm confused where and how to use concrete method...

Comment: section in my first edit goes to `Activity` which contains your `ViewPager` and `Adapter`, not into `Adapter` itself. then you are using `mainViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(onpcl);`. Into your adapter you are copying only this snippet with 'SparseArray'. `AdapterFragment` above is complete, yes, three lines. All your Fragment shoud do smth like this: `public class FirstFragment extends AdapterFragment` (not simply `Fragment`). then all extending Fragment should have implemented `public void pass(int farFarAway)`. My snippets are for multiple classes, you join them in one...

Answer (score 0):

Try reading about Fragment shared elements. Perhaps this is what you are looking for.